# How to fetch a profile image from Firebase Storage of the user who posts a new post?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, firebase-storage

I have an instagram-like app where there is a small user profile image above their image post in the main feed.

I have figured out how to fetch the user profile image of the current user, but I cannot figure out how to fetch the user profile image of the person who added the post. Please see my code below.

How do I fetch the user image who created the post?

My Firebase Database structure is:
[my app] > "posts" > post id > "description", "image", "title", "uid", "userName", "location"

My Firebase Storage structure is:
[my app] > "Users" > uid > "profile_pic.jpg"

I am using Swift 3 and Firebase.

Thank you for any advice!!

```
var eventPosts = NSMutableArray()


@IBOutlet weak var eventPostsTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func logoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
}

func loadData() {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("events").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let eventPostsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for post in eventPostsDictionary {
                self.eventPosts.add(post.value)
            }
            self.eventPostsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.eventPostsTableView.delegate = self
    self.eventPostsTableView.dataSource = self

    loadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.eventPosts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    let event = self.eventPosts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.titleLabel.text = event["title"] as? String
    cell.userNameLabel.text = event["userName"] as? String


    if ("image" as? String) != nil {
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child("Users").child((user?.uid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")
        profilePicRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {

                print("Unable to download image")

            } else {

                if(data != nil)
                {
                    print("User already has image")
                    cell.userProfileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }

        })
    }


    if let imageFileName = event["image"] as? String {
        let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageFileName)")
        imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Success
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.flyerImageView.image = image
                cell.flyerImageView.clipsToBounds = true


            } else {
                // Error
                print("Error downloading image: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: you might need to change error in imageRef to something like err, I have seen problems because of this, but let me look into it.

Comment: thanks for the advice Nivix!